# Do you need close mongoose connection every time in a deployed Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In a real server situation,
do we **really** need close `mongoose` in a deployed Node.js server?

My idea is something like this:

```
mongoose.connect(url, { keepAlive: 120 }).then(
  () => {
    // We are doing something exciting here...

    // After we've done.
    return mongoose.connection.close();
  },
  err => {
    console.error(err);
  }
);
```

I know this work, but is it anti-pattern if we want to `keepAlive` and also close the connection?

The article about why I want to keep it alive is found here:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#keepAlive

This question was asked similar thing but it's for an older version of mongoose:
[Do I need to manually close a mongoose connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371821/do-i-need-to-manually-close-a-mongoose-connection)

**Note:**
I'm using `"mongoose": "^5.0.3"`, the supported functions have changed from 4.
In mongoose 5.0.3 documentation, there is nowhere to find it requires to close connection, and the official example also doesn't include it.

Comment: You should only close mongoose's default connection pool when your app exits. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: But in a real server, do you ever want to close the Node.js app?

Comment: Not always, no. Don't worry about it in that case.

Comment: @LeekInPajama if you are using serverless then in this case you have to close the connection after execution of yr code, otherwise no worries.