# Mongoose connection really needs to be closed?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Is it necessary to close the mongoose connection using `mongoose.connection.close()` in code.

When will it be necessary to include this?

Comment: close it only if server shutdown, no need to reconnect in every query.

Comment: refer similar question [Do I need to manually close a mongoose connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371821/do-i-need-to-manually-close-a-mongoose-connection)